# Can I deploy a contract without being fully synced to the Ethereum network?

Tags: contract-deployment

So I've had huge problem to get the Ethereum network to sync.
I've tried several times, even on different computers.
Trying to remove the old DB and run "geth --fast cache=1024".
Anyhow, my current sync has stopped a few hundred blocks from the finish line and it just keeps downloading chain structure.

I'd like to deploy a contract and I don't think I can use https://remix.ethereum.org/ since I need to use the [Open Zeppelin Framework](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity).
**Is it possible to deploy contracts without the network being synced?**

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need to sync with testnet to test your contracts**, you can create and use your own private chain.

There are some ways to do it:

- use `geth`. There is a very convinient tool called `puppeth` for setting your own private chain. `puppeth` is distributed in [`Geth & tools`](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/).
- another way (which IMO is easier) is to become aquainted with [Truffle](http://truffleframework.com/) and [TestRPC](http://truffleframework.com/ganache/).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to connect to the mainnet, not testnets, have you tried using [light client mode](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol)? Much easier to connect to the mainnet this way, and it does allow you to deploy contracts.

```
geth --syncmode light console
```